# Google Analytics goal tracking with multiple CF7 Forms

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have a WordPress website and use Google Analytics to track submission of a CF7 form via goals. I have recently added a second form and would like to track this as a separate goal. I've tried altering the event create using this following script:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if (event.detail.contactFormId == '770' {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Consultation Request', 'submit');
}
    else {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit');
}
}, false );
</script>
```

This still don't seem to separate the forms when I track the events created. Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding this custom script, I ended up using a plugin called [Contact Form 7 Submission DOM tracking](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-submission-dom-tracking/) This plug added the code needed to create separate goals. Also has a few extra features such as the ability to hind the form after submission.